# Material DateRangePicker enable Accept button with single date

Tags: android, material-components-android, daterangepicker

I have a material daterangepicker to select a single date or a range. If i want to select a single date i must select the same date twice to enable "Accept" button. There are something to enable Accept button when select the first date?

I see in [MaterialDatePicker.java](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/datepicker/MaterialDatePicker.java) that they use:

```
pickerFragment.addOnSelectionChangedListener(
    new OnSelectionChangedListener<S>() {
      @Override
      public void onSelectionChanged(S selection) {
        updateHeader();
        confirmButton.setEnabled(dateSelector.isSelectionComplete());
      }

      @Override
      public void onIncompleteSelectionChanged() {
        confirmButton.setEnabled(false);
      }
    });
```

I think i need to use this or something similar but i cant access to this method.

I use this to show DateRangePicker:

```
private fun showDatePicker() {
    val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.dateRangePicker()
    builder.setTheme(R.style.CustomCalendarDatePickerTheme)
    builder.setCalendarConstraints(limitRange().build())

    val picker = builder.build()
    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        tv_date.text = formatRange(it.first!!, it.second!!)
        startDate = it.first
        endDate = it.second
    }

    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
}
```

Comment: You are using a dateRangePicker. If you want a single date use a singlePicker.

Comment: But i use dateRangePicker because i want a range too

Comment: The accept button in this case is available when a range is selected. It is the reason because you have to select 2 dates (or the same date twice).

Comment: As it is a date range picker, the correct UI/UX will be to select same date twice to select a range of a single day. Why do you need to enable Accept button on single date?

Comment: It's a bit awkward to select the same thing twice

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I create a class that extend RangeDateSelector and overriding select() function, when is the first time I set the date in both start and end:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
class CustomMaterialDatePicker : RangeDateSelector() {

    private var first = true
    private var firstDate: Long? = null

    override fun select(selection: Long) {
        if (first || selection < firstDate!!) {
            super.select(selection)
            super.select(selection)
            firstDate = selection
            first = false
        } else {
            super.select(firstDate!!)
            super.select(selection)
            if (selection != firstDate) {
                first = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I create DateRangePicker like this:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private fun showDatePicker() {
    val selector = CustomMaterialDatePicker()
    val builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.customDatePicker(selector)
    builder.setTheme(R.style.CustomCalendarDatePickerTheme)
    builder.setCalendarConstraints(limitRange().build())

    val picker = builder.build()
    picker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener {
        tv_date.text = formatRange(it.first!!, it.second!!)
        startDate = it.first
        endDate = it.second
    }

    picker.show(supportFragmentManager, picker.toString())
}
```